# Redirecting http to https using a Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, google-chrome-extension, https, localhost

I am developing a number of Node.js applications that use an `https` server. While I am developing them, I run them on `localhost` using a self-signed certificate. Basically, everything works, but I have two issues:

1. When I point my browser to `https://localhost:3000` for the first time, it warns me about a non-trusted certificate. This is, of course, true (and important), but it's annyoing while developing. Of course, I could add the certificate as a trusted one, but they change from time to time, and I don't want to clutter the certificate store.
2. Sometimes I just forget to enter the `https` part into the address bar, so Chrome tries to load the website using `http`. For whatever reason Chrome does not realize that there is no webserver responding to `http`requests, instead it loads and loads and loads and …

What I would like to do to solve both issues is to create a Chrome extension that resides next to the address bar and offers a button with which you can toggle its state:

- If the extension is disabled, it does nothing at all.
- If the extension is enabled, and you send a request to `localhost` (and only then!), it shall do two things:

  1. If the request uses `http`, but the page is still `pending` after a few seconds, it shall try using `https` instead.
  2. Temporarily accept any certificate, no matter whether it's trusted by the browser or not.

To make it explicit: These rules shall only active for `localhost`.

So, now my questions are:

- Is something like this possible using a Chrome extension at all?
- As I have absolutely zero experience with writing Chrome extension, what would be a good starting point, and what terms should I look for on Google?

Comment: The **[Google Chrome Extensions Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/index.html)** is a great place to start. Everything you describe is possible using a Chrome Extension **except** for the certificate accepting part. (I am not saying it is not possible, I just don't know if it is - but I would be very surprised (and concerned) if it were.) Of course, there is always the `--ignore-certificate-errors` command-line switch, but it will **not** differentiate between localhost and others.

Comment: Thanks for pointing all this out, it's very helpful :-). Just one more question: Would you recommend using the webRequest API, or a simple content-script?

Comment: I don't think content scripts will be of much use to you. I would go for **[chrome.webRequest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html)** and **[chrome.tabs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html)**

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot :-). If you want - could you convert your comments into an answer? Then I'm going to accept it.

Comment: Now there is an answer I want you to accept :D

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot :-)! I *DO* accept that, definitely :-)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **[Google Chrome Extensions Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/index.html)** is a great place to start. Everything you describe is possible using a Chrome Extension **except** for the "certificate accepting" part. (I am not saying it is not possible, I just don't know if it is - but I would be **very** surprised (and concerned) if it were.)

Of course, there is always the `--ignore-certificate-errors` command-line switch, but it will not differentiate between `localhost` and other domains.

If you decide to implement the rest of the functionality, I suggest looking into **[chrome.tabs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html)** and/or **[chrome.webRequest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html)** first. (Let me, also, mention "content scripts" are unlikely to be of any use.)

---

That said, below is some code for a demo extension (just to get you started).

*What is does:*
When deactivated -> nothing
When activated -> Listens for tabs being directed to URLs like `http://localhost[:PORT][/...]` and redirects them to `https` (it does not wait for a response or anything, it just redirects them instantly).

*How to use:*
Click the browser-action icon to activate/deactivate.

It's not perfect/complete, of course, but it's a starting point :)

---

**Extension directory structure:**

```
        extention-root-directory/
         |_____ manifest.json
         |_____ background.js
         |_____ img/
                 |_____ icon19.png
                 |_____ icon38.png
```

**manifest.json:**
(See **[here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html)** for more info on the possible fields.)

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",
    "default_locale": "en",
    "offline_enabled": true,
    "incognito":       "split",

    // The background-page will listen for
    // and handle various types of events
    "background": {
        "persistent": false,   // <-- if you use chrome.webRequest, 'true' is required
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },

    // Will place a button next to the address-bar
    // Click to enable/disable the extension (see 'background.js')
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Test Extension"
        //"default_icon": {
        //    "19": "img/icon19.png",
        //    "38": "img/icon38.png"
        //},
    },

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",                  // <-- let me manipulating tab URLs
        "http://localhost:*/*"   // <-- let me manipulate tabs with such URLs 
    ]
}
```

**background.js:**
(Related docs: **[background pages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html)**, **[event pages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html)**, **[browser actions](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html)**, **[chrome.tabs API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html)**)

```
/* Configuration for the Badge to indicate "ENABLED" state */
var enabledBadgeSpec = {
    text: " ON ",
    color: [0, 255, 0, 255]
};
/* Configuration for the Badge to indicate "DISABLED" state */
var disabledBadgeSpec = {
    text: "OFF",
    color: [255, 0, 0, 100]
};


/* Return whether the extension is currently enabled or not */
function isEnabled() {
    var active = localStorage.getItem("active");
    return (active && (active == "true")) ? true : false;
}

/* Store the current state (enabled/disabled) of the extension
 * (This is necessary because non-persistent background pages (event-pages)
 *  do not persist variable values in 'window') */
function storeEnabled(enabled) {
    localStorage.setItem("active", (enabled) ? "true" : "false");
}

/* Set the state (enabled/disabled) of the extension */
function setState(enabled) {
    var badgeSpec = (enabled) ? enabledBadgeSpec : disabledBadgeSpec;
    var ba = chrome.browserAction;
    ba.setBadgeText({ text: badgeSpec.text });
    ba.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ color: badgeSpec.color });
    storeEnabled(enabled);
    if (enabled) {
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(localhostListener);
        console.log("Activated... :)");
    } else {
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(localhostListener);
        console.log("Deactivated... :(");
    }
}

/* When the URL of a tab is updated, check if the domain is 'localhost'
 * and redirect 'http' to 'https' */
var regex = /^http(:\/\/localhost(?::[0-9]+)?(?:\/.*)?)$/i;
function localhostListener(tabId, info, tab) {
    if (info.url && regex.test(info.url)) {
        var newURL = info.url.replace(regex, "https$1");
        chrome.tabs.update(tabId, { url: newURL });
        console.log("Tab " + tabId + " is being redirected to: " + newURL);
    }
}

/* Listen for 'browserAction.onClicked' events and toggle the state  */
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    setState(!isEnabled());
});

/* Initially setting the extension's state (upon load) */
setState(isEnabled());
```

Comment: Hey man, I really liked your answer, hence I awarded you a bounty of +100 afterwards. I hope you enjoy it :-)

Comment: Wow, that's my first bounty !!! I don't know what to say. Thx a lot - I really, really enjoyed it :D :D :D